# Hashing to cells with index not an int (in C#)

Tags: c#, hash, hashtable

I am looking to do something that is a bit odd: I have a text file where I consider each line to be a sentence.

Usually the buckets of a hash table are 0,1,...

For my specific problem, I would like to hash the sentence in a way that if two sentences have the same number of words then they will be hashed to the same bucket.

Moreover, I would also like for the content of the sentence to be used for the hashing, and I don't want too many items in each bucket - so I thought I will hash each sentence to a bucket which is an ordered pair (a,b) where a is the number of words in the sentence and b is some number I got from the content of the sentence (say look at it as integer and use some hash function such as %p where p is prime)

Of course, that if no item is hashed to some (a,b) I don't want to create this bucket - and in other words I want the bucket to be created only when something is hashed to it) - so creating a large table with size number_of_options_to_a * p is not a good solution (it would take too much space in my case).

Is there an 'easy' way to achieve this in C# (i.e there is some class that I can use) or do I have to code such a hash table myself (which I can do but I would much rather use an existing class)

Note: this also means that the load factor should not be taken care of by this class, that is if I chose p then I want a maximum of p buckets (per given length)

I have looked at the Hashtable class and I couldn't see a way to do it with it.

Any advice is appreciated!

ADDED: After I insert all sentences I would like that given some sentence to calculate (a,b) that it was hashed to and to be able to look at all the elements in other given buckets, say (a+1,b)

Comment: Can you explain why this is necessary to solve your problem? It sounds very low level optimization to me, but it could solve your problem I guess. To (partly) solve your problem, if you override `GetHashCode` in the object that you are storing in the buckets, then you can specify how the hash is calculated. It doesn't give you a way to specify the amount of objects per bucket.

Comment: @Maarten - this is for an exercise in a Big Data course (on coursera) so optimizations are needed to make small number of comparisons between pairs of sentences. (I don't check if they are the same, but their content does matter for the comparison so I wanted to get some information based on what bucket the sentence is hashed to so I could consider a few buckets as candidates)

Comment: Questions about coursework should probably be directed to your teacher or TA. That said, the built-in hashtable-based data structures in .NET are reasonably efficient, up to their inherent capacities (.NET restricts their internal storage size, which results in maximum capacities around the tens of millions of elements mark). You could, for example, use a Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, List<int>>> where the outer key (int) is the word count, the inner key (string) is the sentence itself, and the inner value (int) is the list of line #'s where the sentence was found.